# Deleted vs. closed questions

Tags: discussion

I'm writing here re this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283068/how-to-add-an-existing-user-into-a-group-in-linux/

It was a quite popular question, ranked 1st on google for even basic queries like **linux user** or **linux group**, also having more than 140K views in not even two years.

I don't know why it got deleted, considering it was already closed with a warning it's not a programming question.

**So, the question is:** Why are some questions deleted rather than just closed? Take a look at this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-windows

Why does this one have the privilege to live, despite having the same problem? I think we should debate on this subject and make some guidelines, then stick to them rigorously.

Comment: I agree. A historical lock would have been better IMO.

Comment: Those questions were asked three years apart. I question why "How to add an existing user into a group in Linux?" was asked on Stack Overflow to begin with, when Super User already existed in 2011. A historical lock might have been better, but I'd really rather reserve those for questions that were at least on-topic at the time they were asked.

Comment: See my answer below. We want to make internet better. Previously, this answer was nr. 1 on Google, now this one is in its place: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/
Judge the quality by yourself.

Comment: Having the #1 spot on Google does not automatically mean we're making the Internet better. There's no value added if the information is the same.

Comment: Did you lose the rep by the way? How does it work?

Answer (score 5):

This question is off-topic. It is not even about programming. It doesn't really matter whether it is popular or not. Questions like this are simply to be deleted.

When you answered that question, it was already off-topic (and closed in 2 hours). You still decided to answer it. The consequences are logical, and were logical at that time too. I understand it is a bad feeling to lose such a high-scoring answer, but it was your decision to answer instead of flagging/closing (depending on your privileges at that time).

The other question is just like that. Why it wasn't deleted, you ask. Luck, I guess. Now it got enough attention so it will be deleted as it should have been already.

Keeping these questions does not make the internet a better place. I am sure the same information can already be found on [Super](https://superuser.com/questions/487296/how-do-i-add-users-to-another-users-group) [User](https://superuser.com/questions/95972/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-multiple-groups-in-ubuntu), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110325/trying-to-form-group-with-two-users), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/add-user-to-existing-group) (maybe even Server Fault). It has no place on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you have [10k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you can vote to delete a question.  A question with a lot of upvotes requires more delete-votes before it is deleted.

An endless stream of off-topic questions arrives at SO every day.  Most of them receive little attention and no votes.  So just being off-topic is not enough to be closed or deleted.

To be closed or deleted, you have to trigger a strong sense of dislike in voters with 10k rep.  One reason for dislike is if someone else gains a lot of reputation by a stroke of luck.  That tends to happen if a question is the top Google answer for a common problem.  Reputation envy may explain why this question was singled out.

The official goal of SO is to improve the internet.  A popular question with good answers does just that, even if it's off-topic.  If the question were not locked by a moderator, I'd vote to undelete or re-open it.

Comment: Does it really improve the Internet if the answer to that question was already easy to find on Google?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. However, my point still stands, we lack guidelines. We do not want to deal with important problems relying solely on emotion.

@BilltheLizard: IMO, this answer is the most accurate. The first 2 results now contain outdated information from 2006, contained within a lengthy article. We improve the internet if we provide, short, quick and to-the-point answers.

Comment: @RokKralj The first Google result was just updated in April 2014, more recently than the answer on Stack Overflow. It's not outdated.

Comment: "To be closed or deleted, you have to trigger a strong sense of dislike in voters with 10k rep" - no need to bring emotions into this. This is a programming Q&A site. If something is so clearly off-topic, it should be deleted regardless of its score, -10 or 200, it does not matter. We should not keep them even with a historical lock.

Comment: Note that a majority of closed questions do get deleted eventually, many of them automatically by the system. Moderators and 10K users are responsible for the rest, as when a question has been found useful it is important that human judgement is used rather than simple heuristics.